# Wait for multiple threads (Posix threads, c++)

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads

Consider the following situation:

I have an object foo that is used by multiple threads, that may or may not repeatedly call a method bar() on foo.

It is perfectly fine (and desired) that bar() is executed multiple times in parallel, as it never changes the state of foo.

The problem arises when i need to change the state of foo from the outside (from another thread, not from one of the "worker" threads) - how can i lock foo in a way so that the calling thread blocks until the last worker thread is done with bar() and all worker threads will block at bar() until i release foo again?

Obviously i cannot just use a mutex that is remains locked during execution of bar(), because then i won't have concurrency there.

Any ideas? Or is there a better design for those types of problems?

Comment: See [Readers–writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

Comment: why not introducing a mutex in the worker threads around the calling of the bar function and on also on the calling thread which wants to change foos state. the calling thread locks the mutex and can than safely change foo's state.

Comment: `pthread_rwlock_t` may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how you are going to achieve, that none of *workers* are using foo to let *writer* update it, but if it is not of a concern then just use a [read/write mutex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_wrlock) (*workers* to obtain read lock, *writer* to obtain write lock).

It is worth mentioning though, that you might want to consider making foo Copy-on-Write. This way you will make synchronization overhead close to zero. You can use [shared_ptr atomically](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) to achieve that.